# U-SQL, Python, local execution, "device not found" error

Tags: python, azure, u-sql

I'm trying to run a U-SQL job with Python extension locally using VS 2017.

I followed these steps:

1. https://1drv.ms/w/s!AvdZLquGMt47g0NultCKgm38sejs
2. https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/azuredatalake/2017/02/20/enabling-u-sql-advanced-analytics-for-local-execution/

And then I tried to run this:

3. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-lake-analytics/data-lake-analytics-u-sql-python-extensions

It works fine if I run it in Azure, but if I try to run it locally, the error I get is: "The device is not read".

Details:

```
Start : 2017-08-16 14:35:13
Initialize : 2017-08-16 14:35:13
GraphParse : 2017-08-16 14:35:13
Run : 2017-08-16 14:35:13
Start 'Root' : 2017-08-16 14:35:13
End 'Root(Success)' : 2017-08-16 14:35:13
Start '1_SV1_Extract' : 2017-08-16 14:35:13
End '1_SV1_Extract(Error)' : 2017-08-16 14:35:14
Completed with 'Error' : 2017-08-16 14:35:14
Execution failed with error '1_SV1_Extract Error : '{"diagnosticCode":195887147,"severity":"Error","component":"RUNTIME","source":"User","errorId":"E_RUNTIME_USER_UNHANDLED_EXCEPTION_FROM_USER_CODE","message":"An unhandled exception from user code has been reported","description":"Unhandled exception from user code: \"The device is not ready.\r\n\"\nThe details includes more information including any inner exceptions and the stack trace where the exception was raised.","resolution":"Make sure the bug in the user code is fixed.","helpLink":"","details":"==== Caught exception System.IO.IOException\n\n   at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)\r\n   at System.IO.Directory.InternalCreateDirectory(String fullPath, String path, Object dirSecurityObj, Boolean checkHost)\r\n   at System.IO.Directory.InternalCreateDirectoryHelper(String path, Boolean checkHost)\r\n   at System.IO.Compression.ZipFileExtensions.ExtractToDirectory(ZipArchive source, String destinationDirectoryName)\r\n   at System.IO.Compression.ZipFile.ExtractToDirectory(String sourceArchiveFileName, String destinationDirectoryName, Encoding entryNameEncoding)\r\n   at Microsoft.MetaAnalytics.LanguageWorker.UsqlPyExecution.LocatePython(String version) in C:\\Users\\shravan\\Source\\Repos\\VSTS\\USqlExtensions\\lang\\python\\AFx\\Product\\Source\\Modules\\LanguageWorker\\LanguageWorker.Dll\\UsqlExecution.cs:line 146\r\n   at Microsoft.MetaAnalytics.LanguageWorker.UsqlPyExecution.InvokeLanguage(String version, String scriptname, IList`1 infiles, IList`1 outfiles, IObserver`1 stringLogger) in C:\\Users\\shravan\\Source\\Repos\\VSTS\\USqlExtensions\\lang\\python\\AFx\\Product\\Source\\Modules\\LanguageWorker\\LanguageWorker.Dll\\UsqlExecution.cs:line 89\r\n   at Microsoft.MetaAnalytics.LanguageWorker.UsqlPyExecution.Run(IRowset input, IUpdatableRow output, String script, String version) in C:\\Users\\shravan\\Source\\Repos\\VSTS\\USqlExtensions\\lang\\python\\AFx\\Product\\Source\\Modules\\LanguageWorker\\LanguageWorker.Dll\\UsqlExecution.cs:line 42\r\n   at Extension.Python.Reducer.<Reduce>d__6.MoveNext() in C:\\Users\\shravan\\Source\\Repos\\VSTS\\USqlExtensions\\lang\\python\\ExtPy\\PyReducer.cs:line 56\r\n   at ScopeEngine.SqlIpReducer<Extract_0_Data0,Process_1_Data0,ScopeEngine::KeyComparePolicy<Extract_0_Data0,3> >.GetNextRow(SqlIpReducer<Extract_0_Data0\\,Process_1_Data0\\,ScopeEngine::KeyComparePolicy<Extract_0_Data0\\,3> >* , Process_1_Data0* output) in c:\\users\\e\\source\\repos\\usqlapplication1\\usqlapplication1\\bin\\debug\\1b720f51a8b3caea\\script_fe316531c87f021f\\sqlmanaged.h:line 2788\r\n   at std._Func_class<void>.()(_Func_class<void>* )\r\n   at RunAndHandleClrExceptions(function<void __cdecl(void)>* code)","internalDiagnostics":""}
'
'
Execution failed !
```

I'm aware that the blog post mentions that running Python extensions locally is not officially supported, but they do make it sound like it should at least be possible somehow?

I don't get any errors if I run U-SQL scripts without using the Python extension locally.

Is there anything I'm missing? Is there any logging I could turn on to find out more? Has anyone had success running Python with U-SQL locally?

Comment: I reached out to the team owning local run to see if they can help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

(Azure Data Lake team here)

There was a recent update in how the Python distribution is located in the Azure Data Lake Analytics service. While the change improved vertex startup times, it also broke some basic assumptions on how local execution of U-SQL scripts works.

The team is working on an alternative solution that will let a locally executing U-SQL script use an existing Python distribution that is installed on the same local machine.

Comment: Is there an update to this? I am still struggling to get python in U-SQL to work locally.